# Dual Camera Issue

Tags: camera

I recently set up my raspberry pi to run as a home
security camera. I am using a pi NoIR camera module and the raspi cam web interface software.

It works perfectly, however I am simultaneously trying to run a usb webcam for video chat (using the jitsi app) on chromium web browser. Oddly, chromium shows the usb camera in settings but I can’t select it. Instead, the NoIR camera module is automatically selected and it does not work.

When I disable the camera module in raspi-config and reboot, the usb webcam suddenly works with no issues. Is there a way to run both cameras at the same time? Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!